# Why is here the preimage of each point open and closed?

Tags: continuity, connectedness

I consider a connected topological space $X$ and a discrete space $Y$. Then we look at $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a continuous function. I don't see why the preimage of each $y\in Y$ should be open and closed in $X$.

Could someone maybe explain this to me, because in my opinion the only open and closed subset in a connected space are $\emptyset, X$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Given your opinion, what can you say about $f$?

Comment: It's true that in a connected space, only $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open and closed. The consequence is simply that the preimage of a singleton in this case can only be $X$ or $\emptyset$, so there's no problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous and $\{y\}$ is both open and closed (since $Y$ is discrete), $f^{-1}\bigl(\{y\}\bigr)$ is both open and closed.

Comment: but why do we need $f$ to be continuous in order that $\{y\}$ is open and closed?

Comment: We don't and I never claimed otherwise. We use the fact that $Y$ is discrete to deduce that $\{y\}$ is both closed and open and then we use the fact that $f$ is continuous to deduce that its pre-image is closed and open.

Comment: ah sorry, sure. Perfect thanks!